# Swift 3 - Can not get label - creating in code - to match width when rotating to landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift3, rotation, autolayout

I created a UILabel in my Swift 3 code (I have some labels on storyboard and those resize just fine when rotating, it is just the ones I create in swift code that don't resize so clearly I am doing it wrong).  I want the width to match the width of the view it is in.  When I create it, it sizes correctly but when the view is rotated to landscape mode, it does not resize.  I started by adding NSLayoutConstraint for the right of the label to match the right side of the view, but I kept having issues.  After diving into the documentation, I found that it is safer and more appropriate to use NSLayoutAnchor to perform this task.  The doc says it can catch more autolayout issues at compile time.  I found that to be the case and it is a but easier to understand and use.  But, it still does not work.  When the view is rotated, the label stays the same width.

```
    // Swim Title
    newXPosition = 4
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: newXPosition, y: newYPosition, width: labelParentView.frame.width - 4, height: SPLIT_HEIGHT))
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.text = "Swim Splits"
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    self.labelParentView.addSubview(label)
    // Creating the same constraints using Layout Anchors
    let margins = labelParentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    labelParentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this...

A. Tell the label to use an autoresizing mask:

```
    self.labelParentView.addSubview(label)
    // use autoresizing mask
    label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // don't need anything else
    //let margins = labelParentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    //label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    //labelParentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

or, B. Turn *off* autoresizing mask, and add constraints:

```
    self.labelParentView.addSubview(label)

    // turn off autoresizing mask
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // add constraints
    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelParentView.leftAnchor, constant: 4.0).isActive = true
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelParentView.topAnchor, constant: 4.0).isActive = true
    label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelParentView.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: SPLIT_HEIGHT).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks.  Works like a charm

Comment: @PaulLinck - be sure to "accept" the answer, for other people who come across this question.

Comment: OK.  I just did.  I was not able to until recently since my reputation was too low.  Thanks again.